# rand() function always generation same number despite seeding with time

Tags: c, macos

I have this code I need to write, and I created this function. Irrelevant of what it does for the code, I need it to generate a random number (`a`) between `0` and (`i`), an integer with a previously initialized value. Somehow despite seeding, I always get the same number.

I have tried entering a number instead of i and it works properly by giving me a different random number each time I execute. I also tried declaring a new `int` variable inside in the function and giving it the value of `i`, but it still doesn't work.

```
elementptr position_current(elementptr first, int i){
  elementptr current = first;
  int j = 1;

  printf("%d\n", i);
  srand(time(NULL));

  int a = rand() % i;
  printf("%d\n",a);
  for(j=1;j<a;j++){
    current = current->next;
  }

  return current;
}
```

I expect (`a`) to get a different value each Time I run the code, however it's always getting the same value(2).
Can someone tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: You should call `srand()` only once, at the beginning of the program. Subsequent calls to `rand()` will change the seed and produce pseudo-trandom numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're calling this function many times in a single second. Since `time` only changes once a second, you're reseeding the same value over and over.

Don't call `srand` over and over. Call it exactly once in your `main` function, then never call it again, and `rand` will produce successive values based on that seed one at a time.